# Is there value to signing microservice calls with an HMAC derived from the same private key?

Tags: openssl, hmac, hashicorp-vault

I had a friend say:

> We're securing our microservice with an HMAC derived from the private key in the jks file. [Where client and server shared the same private key]

I can understand the situation where you have an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) from a secret that is short lived - such as one derived from [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

But if the HMAC has the same lifetime as the private keys - why not just secure the [microservice](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) using [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) based on the [private keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) you've already installed?

My question is: **Is there value to signing microservice calls with an HMAC derived from the same private key?**

Comment: What private key? Typically a private key would only be known by one end. If the client generates the hash, the server has no way to verify.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful. I've clarified the question to state that both client and server share the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If client and server share the same private key, private key basically turns into as a symmetric secret, thus nullifying any use-case relevant for SSL, or, FWIW, any signing scheme.

It's basically integrity without authenticity.